# How to show the todays date in VF Email template in salesforce

Tags: email-template, vf-email-template

I am using `{!Today}` in a Custom Email Template and it is showing today's date.

But I need to change the template to VF template and I am getting a error.

Can suggest how can I show today's date without creating any new formula field  and populating in the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In visualforce you need to use `{!TODAY()}`. Also you can use Year, Month and Day to format it any way you want it. For example:

```
{!DAY(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!YEAR(TODAY())}
{!MONTH(TODAY())}/{!DAY(TODAY())}/{!YEAR(TODAY())}
```

You can check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) for a full list of visualforce functions.

Comment: but it is showing a full date with time Mon Jul 25 00:00:00 GMT 2016...I just want date

Comment: @ajaybagdad added an example